# Element out of viewport

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

There is a long page, like Amazon, and I want to work on an element visible only if I vertically scroll. Will Selenium find the element without scrolling? My tests show different results for different elements.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on technology implemented on that web page.
There are sites / pages loading only elements inside the visible viewport.
There are some other sites / pages loading more than the visible viewport, but still not the entire current page.
There are sites / pages loading all the elements on the current page. But even in this case the invisible element may be initially created so you can locate them and scroll to them, but they will not contain their text contents etc.
And finally there are some sites that are initially loading all the elements, even elements out of the visible viewports, so as all the elements there will be initially fully rendered, including their text contents etc.